# How to declare useState conditonally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For my problem , right now I am getting data from api like this.

```
const fetchSomething = () => dispatch => {
    return axios
        .get('productsapi/getsomething', {
        })
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_SOMETHING,
                payload: res.data[0].Groups[0].Products,
                payGroup: res.data[0],
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('fetching error');
            throw err;
        });
};
```

As you can see I am getting 2 kind of data from an api `payload` and `paygroup` because of the problem I encountering in the component.

Here is the component

```
let hotProductList = useSelector(state => state.productReducer.hotProduct);
let hotProductGroup = useSelector(
        state => state.productReducer.newHotProductGroups,
);

const [homeHotProductList, setHomeHotProductList] = useState(hotProductGroup.Groups[0].Products);

//No Error
//---------
//const [homeHotProductList, setHomeHotProductList] = useState(hotProductList); 
//---------
```

As you can see in the `useState`. If I want to render the `initial productList` using data from `payGroup` I have to declare like `useState(hotProductGroup.Groups[0].Products)` . The problem is that, this kind of declaring always return error which state that

**`undefined is not an object`**

But If I want to render the `initial productList` using data from `payload` this error does not occur.

What Should I do to make the `declaration works` for the `payGroup` without getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `homeHotProductList` is an array. You can set your `homeHotProductList` in `useEffect`. Add `hotProductList` and `hotProductGroup` as dependency to `useEffect`. So whenever these value changes you can set `homeHotProductList` using `setHomeHotProductList` inside `useEffect` conditionally.

```
let hotProductList = useSelector(state => state.productReducer.hotProduct);
let hotProductGroup = useSelector(
        state => state.productReducer.newHotProductGroups,
);

const [homeHotProductList, setHomeHotProductList] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
 // here you can set homeHotProductList conditionally

}, [hotProductList, hotProductGroup])
```

And regarding this error

> undefined is not an object

You can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) if you're not getting value like `hotProductGroup?.Groups?.[0]?.Products ?? []`